# Google PubSub and GCM

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, publish-subscribe

My project has a requirement of pushing notifications to android mobile phones based on certain events. (I need a gcm)

Users of the mobile phones can subscribe to these events and hence I need a pub/sub.

Now, google pub/sub service can help me build the pub sub but it can only 'push' notifications to an HTTPS DOMAIN server, which we don't have. 
Is there a way I can direct google pub/sub push service directly to the gcm, which then can push it to the respective mobile phones? (assuming its all google in the background and hence must have this facility)

Comment: Have a look at the Realtime Messaging integration with GCM (and APNS). You get the pub/sub semantics from Realtime with the GCM transport for Android Push Notifications (and Apple Push Notifications with APNS). 

See [http://messaging-public.realtime.co/documentation/starting-guide/mobilepush.html](http://messaging-public.realtime.co/documentation/starting-guide/mobilepush.html) and [http://messaging-public.realtime.co/documentation/starting-guide/mobilePushGCM.html](http://messaging-public.realtime.co/documentation/starting-guide/mobilePushGCM.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can push directly to your mobile topic subscribers. Take a look at GCM PubSub:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmPubSub